# Failed to test ValueError in pytest when calling a function that using try/except to catch exception

Tags: python, pytest

I have this code that basically just to find out people age in minutes:

```
import datetime, inflect, operator, sys


Inflect = inflect.engine()


def main():
    # Ask user for their dob, Wait for return of final year minutes in words
    print(get_year(input("Date of Birth: ")))


def get_year(date):
    # Get and Validate user DOB input
    try:
        # Split each YY MM DD based on -
        date = date.split("-")

        # Convert user input to datetime format
        date = datetime.date(int(date[0]), int(date[1]), int(date[2]))

        # Get years distance between user's input date and today's date
        years_distance = operator.sub(datetime.date.today(), date)

        # Get user age in minutes: Convert years distance to minutes by divide seconds to 60
        # Also Convert to int so we don't get float as result, which we don't want word 'point zero'
        years_distance_in_minutes = int(years_distance.total_seconds() / 60)

        # Conver string numbers to words
        return convert_to_words(years_distance_in_minutes)
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit("Invalid date")


def convert_to_words(minutes):
    # Convert number to words with inflect engine
    words = Inflect.number_to_words(minutes, andword="")
    return words.capitalize() + " minutes"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this is my pytest code:

```
import pytest
from seasons import get_year


def test_valid_get_year():
    assert get_year("2022-05-22") == "Five hundred twenty-five thousand, six hundred minutes"
    assert get_year("2021-05-22") == "One million, fifty-one thousand, two hundred minutes"
    assert get_year("1997-11-06") == "Thirteen million, four hundred thirty-two thousand, three hundred twenty minutes"


@pytest.mark.parametrize("date", ["cat", "22/05/202", "November 6, 1997", "1999-13-30", "3000-11-06"])
def test_invalid_get_year(date):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_year(date)
```

If you look at my `get_year()` function, it will perfectly handle **any** Invalid Format Date using `try/except` and will `sys.exit("Invalid date")` immediately.

But when I run pytest, this code is always failed:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("date", ["cat", "22/05/202", "November 6, 1997", "1999-13-30", "3000-11-06"])
def test_invalid_get_year(date):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        get_year(date)
```

The output is always:

```
       except ValueError:
>           sys.exit("Invalid date")
E           SystemExit: Invalid date


>       with pytest.raises(ValueError):
E       Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>
```

In my understanding, it seems like the pytest didn't work perfectly with `try/except` in my `get_year()` function. There's an example where I don't need to use `try/except` where I can validate each line of code with `if/else` and raise ValueError independently.

But it's there a way to use `try/except` like in my `get_year()` and have `pytest` to passed it?

Comment: Your code catches `ValueError`, it does not raise it - so the test output is correct. You have to test for the `sys.exit` (e.g. for `SystemExit`) instead.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen it's not working. There's a lot of error coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `sys.exit` during the error handling  is a bad practice.
This line of code `with pytest.raises` is essentially an [assertion](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions), telling pytest to expect  an exception from your function `get_year`.

Because it calls `sys.exit`, the program exits before the exception, `ValueError`, can reach pytest, so it complains with this message:

```
E       Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>
```

Remove `sys.exit` and let the python runtime handle the exception for you.

```py
try:
   ...
except ValueError as err:
    log_your_error(err)
    raise # this will re-raise the error so that pytest sees it
```

Comment: Your code is work perfectly. But here's the thing: The goal is to exit via `sys.exit()` when user input Invalid Format Date. How to handle this after catch exception in `try/except`?

Comment: @Kevinkun try and catch the ValueError in the main function and print out the error message and exit there. Even if you do nothing, the Python runtime will print out a default error message and exit.

Comment: I just solved the problem. In `except ValueError:` I do `raise sys.exit("Invalid date")` and in my pytest I change `ValueError` to `SystemExit` `with pytest.raises(SystemExit):`. What do you think of it?

Comment: @Kevinkun Yes. This will also work. The word `raise`  is not necessary there because `sys.exit` internally raises  a SystemExit exception.